# joda time period duration

Tags: android, jodatime

I read the forums and some posts here but still couldn't figure this out:
I have this code segment running in my android emulator and it says i have:

11 months, ***2 days***, 22 hrs, 49 mins, 18 seconds
why is it giving me 2 days? it should be giving me at least ***29-30 days***

```
DateTime laterTimeVar = new DateTime().plusYears(1);
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
     DateTime nowTimeVar = new DateTime();
     Period timeToLater = new Period(nowTimeVar, laterTimeVar);
     String retVal = dateFormatter.print(timeToLater);  
     timer.setText(retVal);
     mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 200) ;
  }
};
```

thanks all(first question here)

Comment: Hi, could you add your initialization code for `dateFormatter`?

Comment: Sorry - nope :( I decided to move to Gregorian Calender instead- Joda time's Jar was 2MB- my apk without it was 4Kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Periods calculate weeks as well as years, months and days by default. If you do a toString on the period object you'll see what happened.

Pass [PeriodType.yearMonthDay()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html#yearMonthDay%28%29) to the Period constructor to get the result you want.